# Add Icon to Placeholder Text in Search Form

Tags: search, fonts

I am trying to add an icon in the placeholder text of my search form as below but i am not getting it to work. Any ideas if this is possible to achieve?

```
 <form role="search" method="get" class="searchform group" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
     <input required type="search" class="search-field" minlength="3" maxlength="50" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( '<i class="x-icon x-icon-angle-right" data-x-icon="" aria-hidden="true"></i>Search', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search...', 'label' ) ?>" /><button type="submit" class="search-submit">[x_icon type="search"]</button></form>
```

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for stackoverflow, since it's not directly related to WordPress (this is an HTML/CSS question). That said, the placeholder attribute should not contain HTML. [Here's a similar question from SO that might help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder) Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `FontAwesome`, you can display an icon in the placeholder text like this :

HTML

```
<input placeholder="&#xf0e0;" class="fontAwesome">
```

CSS

```
.fontAwesome{ font-family: 'Helvetica', FontAwesome, sans-serif; }
```